# PostgreSQL pgAdmin4 " window function X requires an OVER clause LINE 1: select * from X"

Tags: postgresql, function-call, pgadmin-4

Above error is very common but I still couldn't find any solution that helps me. Being new to PostgreSQL I am stuck at function calling where I have defined an easy function that return a column from a table on executing that function but instead its throwing me above error. Here is my function definition and its call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.X()
RETURNS SETOF character varying 
LANGUAGE 'sql'

COST 100
VOLATILE LEAKPROOF STRICT SECURITY DEFINER WINDOW 
ROWS 1000
AS $BODY$

Select id from change where id>= '274'

$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public.X(character varying, character varying)
OWNER TO lke_new;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.X(character varying, character 
varying)
IS 'The function returns the set of X ids';

--function call
select * from X('274','275')
```

Any leads would be really helpful!

Comment: I simply followed the instruction given [here](http://example.comhttps://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/function_dialog.html). And I am not even using any Window function in the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared this function as window function by specifying `WINDOW` in the `CREATE FUNCTION` statement.

Then you try to call it like a normal function. That won't work.

Moreover, the only language you can use to define a window function is C. Like [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) says:

> `WINDOW` indicates that the function is a window function rather than a plain function. This is currently only useful for functions written in C.

I suspect that this is by mistake and all you have to do is to remove the `WINDOW` clause.